# Why does adding a jquery animate method break all the AJAX on the page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I've got an online store app with the cart in a column on the side, in rails. I just successfully added some AJAX which makes just the cart column reload whenever a user clicks "add item to cart". I'm now trying to make the new item in the cart flash highlighted (like the yellow fade effect.)

When I try to do this, it not only doesn't work, it breaks my code which successfully updates the number of items in my cart automatically. The item still gets added to the cart, but you have to refresh to see it. I've isolated the line of code that is breaking it, but I don't know what the problem is. I think I have all the proper gems installed. I've looked around,   been researching this, trying to get the proper gems installed and such for a day now. I think I have them, but there is just a problem with my code I can't see. I don't really know javascript or jquery, I'm mostly a Ruby and Java person.

In the Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

In the line_items_controller (which is for each line item in the cart),

```
def create
  @cart = current_cart
  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)
  @line_item.product = product

  respond_to do |format|
    if @line_item.save
      format.html { redirect_to store_url}
      format.js
      format.json { render json: @line_item,
        status: :created, location: @line_item }
  else
```

In the partial for this column, an html.erb file:

```
<% if line_item == @current_item %>
    <tr id="current_item">
<% else %>
    <tr>
<% end %>
    <td><%=line_item.quantity%>&times;</td>
    <td><%= line_item.product.title%></td>
    <td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price)%></td> 
</tr>
```

In the view, in create.js.erb:

```
$('#cart').html("<%=j render @cart %>");
$('#current_item').css({'background-color: #88ff88'}).animate({"background-color: #114411"}, 1000);
```

This second line, $('#current_item').... is the one that breaks it. The first line was what made the auto-updating cart work, and all the rest of the code, the auto-updating cart works fine. When I add this second line, the auto-updating stops working. The server says it is rendering the partial, but it does nothing.

Am I calling the jquery method properly? Am I running the gem properly? I'm still new to using gems. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a syntax error which was breaking the code. I still don't have the yellow fade working, but the rest of my code is now working.

In create.js.erb, I had:

```
$('#current_item').css({'background-color: #88ff88'}).animate({"background-color: #114411"}, 1000);
```

when I should have had

```
$('#current_item').css({'background-color': '#88ff88'}).animate({"background-color:" "#114411"}, 1000);
```

I didn't get my quotation marks right. I had it `'background-color: #88ff88'` when I should have had two sets, one around background-color and one around the color itself.

I don't have the gem working, and if anyone has answers on that, I'd love to hear them but at least I fixed why the code was breaking.

Answer (score 0):

Inside Download rails32/depot_m/app/views/line_items/_line_item.html.erb

Make sure your your quotes are double not single.

if it is  the highlight will not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty late, but I am just going through the exact same thing. I found your response very helpful, so I'm letting you know what I think is wrong.

On your line_item_controller, you write "format.js" but do not pass in any variables. But in the html.erb file, you do <% if line_item == @current_item %>

because you are not passing in any variable, you are never getting anything in the @current_item. So your if statement always fails and the html.erb will always keep  format instead of

I hope that you have already figured this out though!